# tsc and nested tsconfigs

Tags: typescript, tsc

TS 3.5
I have the following config that works fine with tsserver during development:

```
/tsconfig.json <= "strict": true
  /nested/tsconfig.json <= extends parent tsconfig, "noImplicitThis": false
  /nested/some ts code <= has implicit this
```

So my parent config defines strict true, and most code in the project alings with this rule. But in folder called `nested` there is a code that doesn't comply whit `noImplicitThis`, so I add there `tsconfig.json` that `extends` parent `tsconfig` and has compilerOption `noImplicitThis` set to `false`.

And I get no error while development with `vscode`.

But when I try to do `tsc -p .` (in the root dir) I get the error of "implicit this" in `nested` folder code.

So I don't get how to make this nested/tsconfig.json to be applied to `nested/**` code while compilation of the whole project with `tsc`.